# Is there a lightweight way to obtain the current number of Processes in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process

I want my (C/C++ based) program to display a numeric indicator of how many processes are currently present on the local system.  The number-of-running-processes value would be queried often (e.g. once per second) to update my display.

Is there a lightweight way to get that number?  Obviously I could call "ps ax | wc -l", but I'd prefer not to force the computer to spawn a process and parse several hundred lines of text just to come up with a single integer.

This program will be running primarily under Linux, but it might also run under MacOS/X or Windows also, so techniques relevant to those OS's would be helpful also.

Ideally I'm looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234369/number-of-running-processes-on-a-system-c-question/7295105#7295105), except available under Linux (getsysinfo() appears to be more of a Minix thing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux API to list running processes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes)

Comment: like here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes] ?

Comment: I don't want a list of the running processes though, just a count.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

.... and of course 1 minute after I post the question, I figure out the answer:  [sysinfo](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html) will return (amongst other things) a field that indicates how many processes there are.

That said, if anyone knows of a MacOS/X and/or Windows equivalent to sysinfo(), I'm still interested in that.

---

Update:  Here's the function I finally ended up with.

```
#ifdef __linux__
# include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
# include <sys/sysctl.h>
#elif defined(WIN32)
# include <Psapi.h>
#endif

int GetTotalNumProcesses()
{
#if defined(__linux__)
   struct sysinfo si;
   return (sysinfo(&si) == 0) ? (int)si.procs : (int)-1;
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
   size_t length = 0;
   static const int names[] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
   return (sysctl((int *)names, ((sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]))-1, NULL, &length, NULL, 0) == 0) ? (int)(length/sizeof(kinfo_proc)) : (int)-1;
#elif defined(WIN32)
   DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded;
   return EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded) ? (cbNeeded/sizeof(DWORD)) : -1;
#else
   return -1;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`opendir("/proc")` and count the number of entries that are directories and have digit-only names.